# Padding & Alignment - misunderstanding

Tags: c++, c

Given the following very simple structure:

```
struct A {

    int a;
    double b;

};
```

(Using Mac OS 10.9 - Xcode)

The sizeof the structure is 16. I can't see why. Why isn't it 12? 12 is a multiple of 4. 
What am I missing here?

thanks

EDIT:

```
struct B {

int a;
char b[4];
char c[4];
};
```

The sizeof this structure is 12. So, it means that it is an eligible size. 
Why does the compiler then pad the first structure with another 4 bytes?

Comment: I feel like your title pretty much answers your question.

Comment: Look edit. Added another structure

Comment: If you're aware of alignment and padding, then I would expect you to be aware that `double` is larger than `char` and on most machines that means its alignment requirement is also larger.

Comment: @Rouki I am guessing your machine is 64-bit (both CPU and OS).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

4 isn't a magic number. Alignment is usually done to the size of the scalar object, which in this case is 8 for `double`. But that's not a hard rule. A machine or platform can dictate whatever alignment requirements it wants.

See the [ABI spec](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/abi.pdf) for complete (read: mind-numbing) details.

Comment: @Rouki The alignment is done based on what the hardware wants. On many machines, doubles must be aligned on 8-byte boundaries, or operate faster if they are.

Answer (score 3):

The compiler and architecture likely prefers that the address of `double b` aligns on an 8-byte boundary since `sizeof(double) == 8` just as it prefers that the address of `int a` line up on a 4 byte boundary.

Hence, the compiler is likely inserting 4 bytes of "padding" between "int a" and "double b" such that both variables can line up on an expected boundary.

Most compilers usually offer a way to turn off padding (useful for network/disk serialization), but it's compiler dependent.  On Windows it's `#pragma pack(1)`. On gcc it's `__attribute__ ((packed))`  Not sure if Mac/Clang has a similar attribute.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler needs to add padding to make sure that address of **every member** of a structure should be aligned according to its type.

In this case:

```
struct A {
    int a;
    double b;

};
```

suppose that `sizeof(int)` is 4, `sizeof(double)` is 8, then the address of `a` should be a multiple of 4, the address of `b` a multiple of 8. (This is called natural alignment.) If the base address of a variable of this type is zero, then to make the address of member `b` of this variable satisfy its alignment requirement, compiler needs to add a 4-byte padding after member `a`.

Answer (score 0):

Padding is added in the first case because, on your machine, an `double` is aligned to 8 bytes. So it has to reside at an address that is divisible to 8.

```
0x00 0x01 0x02 0x03 0x04 0x05 0x06 0x07 0x08 0x09 0x0A 0x0B 0x0C 0x0D 0x0E 0x0F 

a    a    a    a    |     padding     | b    b    b    b    b    b    b    b
```

If no padding is added, the `double` member starts at address `0x04`, which is wrong. With  4 added padding bytes. Now the `double` is at `0x08`.
Hence the size is 16.

For the second case:

```
struct B {

 int a;
 char b[4];
 char c[4];
};

0x00 0x01 0x02 0x03 0x04 0x05 0x06 0x07 0x08 0x09 0x0A 0x0B 
a    a    a    a    b[0] b[1] b[2] b[3] c[0] c[1] c[2] c[3]
```

In this case, if again the base address is at 0, then no padding is required as all are aligned.

Try this :

```
struct B {
 char b[5];
 int a;
 char c[4];
};
```

and size will be 16 bytes. Padding is added so that the int member start's at an address divisible by 4.

```
0x00 0x01 0x02 0x03 0x04 0x05 0x06 0x07 0x08 0x09 0x0A 0x0B 0x0C 0x0D 0x0E 0x0F
b[0] b[1] b[2] b[3] b[4] |   padding  | a    a    a    a    c[0] c[1] c[2] c[3]
```